# angular mat-calendar how to change day header color for particular day of weak

Tags: angular, angular-material

Need to customize mat-calendar day header.

I want to change the color of the particular day header to different color for example Monday and Tuesday headers in red color. using DateClass I am able to change the particular day color but unable to customer day header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With CSS**

A simple way to do this is to pass a custom class to the [date-picker panelClass](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker). The day letter is rendered in a th tag and each day does not have a unique indentifire, but selecting by order will solve this.

In your Template:

```
<mat-datepicker #picker panelClass="custom-header"></mat-datepicker>
```

In your css:

```
/** sunday **/
.custom-header .mat-calendar-table-header th:nth-child(1) span {
  color: red;
}
/** monday **/
.custom-header .mat-calendar-table-header th:nth-child(2) span {
  color: green;
}
/** tuesday **/
.custom-header .mat-calendar-table-header th:nth-child(3) span {
  color: pink;
}
/** wednesday **/
.custom-header .mat-calendar-table-header th:nth-child(4) span {
  color: grey;
}
/** thursday **/
.custom-header .mat-calendar-table-header th:nth-child(5) span {
  color: black;
}
/** friday **/
.custom-header .mat-calendar-table-header th:nth-child(6) span {
  color: blue;
}
/** saturday **/
.custom-header .mat-calendar-table-header th:nth-child(7) span {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

If you have different order of the weekdays for instance week start on monday, then you should write for each of these a class and conditionally pass the proper class through panelClass.

**Other possible solution but not recommended**

You could adjust the day color value in the component .ts file and query the days by letter, but as [angular recommend](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#properties) to avoid manipulating dom elements in .ts files if possible. I would go for the css solution.

**Edited**

In case the colors are conditional or dynamic, then setting the color in the component .ts must be an option until Mat-Picker make this easier.

**So here is my dynamic solution**

On Picker open you could query the picker Element by its given id and then query its children (the days letters). Then edit the styles dynamically by the angular Renderer2, which is more secure than setting the color style directly.

Checkout my adjusted [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e36hyh?file=src/styles.css)

Comment: We have to set the color based on condition so we can't use CSS way mentioned here

Comment: My good, no! mat-datepicker has a property [dateClass](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker), that is a function that has as argument the date. You can see in the [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) under the "Datepicker with custom date classes"

Comment: Yes but this only affect the day number and not the day name in the header. I have updated my solution and added the dynamic way